# conversion operator with forward declartation

Tags: c++, operators, overloading, conversion-operator

I'm trying to work with conversion operators in c++ I have 2 classes that I'm trying to convert from one to the other, and I am getting errors:

```
class Cow; //error: forward declaration of 'struct Cow'

class Horse {
public:
    Horse():i(0){}
    Horse(int i):i(i){}
    operator Cow() const { return Cow(i); } // error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Cow'
                                            //error : return type 'struct Cow' is incomplete

private:
    int i;
};

class Cow{
public:
    Cow():i(0){}
    Cow(int i):i(i){}
    operator Horse() const { return Horse(i); }
private:
    int i;
};
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Define the functions outside the classes, after both class definitions are complete.

Comment: To clarify, the problem isn't that you are returning a Cow, return types do not need to be defined at function declarations. the problem is that you have the definition of the function (including allocating space for a Cow, the Cow(i) constructor, the copy/move constructor (if not elided)) all of which have yet to be declared.

Comment: Converting a cow to a horse or vice versa is quite a trick!

Comment: Is there any chance you could give me an example of what you mean MadScienceDreams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Cow;

class Horse {
public:
    Horse():i(0){}
    Horse(int i):i(i){}
    operator Cow() const;                     
private:
    int i;
};

class Cow{
public:
    Cow():i(0){}
    Cow(int i):i(i){}
    operator Horse() const;
private:
    int i;
};

Horse::operator Cow() const { return Cow(i); }                                      
Cow::operator Horse() const { return Horse(i); }
```

Comment: That is great, however I noticed that I only need to apply this solution for Horse, the operator in Cow works as is just fine.

Comment: Yes, you only need it for the topmost class that refers to the one under it.